# migration Struts1 application to Struts 2

Tags: struts2

i want to migrate my struts 1 page to struts 2 but i am facing some problems while moving from one page to another page because i am not able to assign the value of my new page to the java object of the action class.

```
<% AccountInfoTab accountInfoTab = (AccountInfoTab) session.getAttribute(Constants.ACCOUNT_INFO_TAB_FORM_KEY); %>


function getPaymentHistoryPage(newPageNmber) {
  document.accountInfoTab.paymentHistoryPageRequested.value = newPageNmber;
  alert(document.accountInfoTab.paymentHistoryPageRequested);
  document.accountInfoTab.submit(); 
}
```

The above code is working for Struts 1 but the same code is not working for struts 2 . Please give me suggestions how will i assign the new page value to my java object ?

Comment: You'll need to supply more context around what you're doing/trying to do. You have a scriptlet and some JavaScript with no apparent connection between the two.

Comment: Do you have a specific problem or error? You should prepare [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to make things clear.